# Problem deleting massive amount of rows with mariaDB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with about 280 million rows, and I've backed it all up (step 1) and now I'm trying to clear out all the records as they're just not needed once backed up.

I hacked together a few scripts like:

```
$begin=0;
for ($k = 1 ; $k < 280; $k++){  
    mysqli_query( $conn, "delete from this_table where id between 
    ".$begin."000000 and ".$k."000000");
    $begin++;
}
```

I have also tried bringing that down to chunks of even 50k and it completely hangs, what am I missing here?

Would it be easy to just drop this table and recreate it, I feel like this would be faster but could risk a big corruption in the whole database.

Comment: Are you trying to delete all the table in the db, or just a subset?  If it's all, truncating the table is probably the most efficient way.  Just make sure you read the docs and ensure any of the caveats won't cause a problem for you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: Tring to delete every row thats currently in that table

Comment: Truncating the table worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me.

```
MariaDB [myData]> truncate table browserQueries;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (6.161 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a large number of rows is slow in every database, and in MySQL and MariaDB, even with InnoDB, DELETEs tend to serialize really badly.

If you have no foreign keys, it should be safe to `TRUNCATE this_table;`, which is an instantaneous O(1) operation and will give you a clean, empty table, with the caveat that it will reset the AUTO_INCREMENT. You will need to fix it using `ALTER TABLE this_table AUTO_INCREMENT=original_value;`

Going forward, the most optimal way to approach this is almost certainly by using partitions. Partition `this_table` by range on ID with a suitably large range. Once the range is fully backed up and no longer needed, you can `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION ...`, which is also an O(1) operation (instantaneous).